# What is Yamouen/Yamoen?

Tags: translation, meaning

I've been hearing something like yamoen for the meaning of "can't be helped". Similar to shouganai from my guess. I can't find it in any dictionary. Am I getting the word wrong or is it a colloquial Kansai dialect?

It's weird because there's this Tokyo-ben character in a show who just suddenly used it out of nowhere so I don't think it should be a dialect.

Thank you,

Comment: I think it is やむを得ん(Yamuoen). https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84%E3%82%80%E3%82%92%E5%BE%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Comment: @YuuichiTam Almost certainly. That should be fine as the answer I think.